# HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

i'm using html dom parser

i have html code like this and want to parse all LI's from first UL with class blue

```
<html> 
<div id="rhy">
<h2 class="text">Text1</h2>
<ul class="blue">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
<h2 class="text">Text2</h2>
<ul class="blue">
<li>4</li>
<li class="z">5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

and i have php code

```
$res = "";
foreach($html->find('#rhy -> .blue -> li[!class]') as $element) 
{
    $res = $res . $element;
}
echo $res;
```

this code returns

```
<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li>
```

but i want to have

```
<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>
```

i'll be happy if someone know how to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want only first `ul` all `li` elements. You can do it like below:-

```
$res = "";
foreach($html->find('.blue->li',0) as $element) 
{
    $res = $res . $element;
}
echo $res;
```

Output:- `<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>`

Comment: @hivokas  glad to help you

Comment: checked again and now it returns

1liArrayArrayArray<ul class="blue">  <li>1</li>  <li>2</li>  <li>3</li>  </ul>Array73

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do this

```
 <html> 
<div id="rhy">
<h2 class="text">Text1</h2>
<ul id ="yourid" class="blue">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
<h2 class="text">Text2</h2>
<ul class="blue">
<li>4</li>
<li class="z">5</li>
<li>6</li>
</ul>
</div>
</html>
```

And your php

```
$res = "";
foreach($html->find('#rhy -> #yourid -> li[!class]') as $element) 
{
    $res = $res . $element;
}
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($html->find('ul', 0) as $ul) 
{
       foreach($ul->find('li') as $li) 
       {
             $ret = $li->find('.blue');
       }
}
echo $ret
```

This should give you all the li of the first ul with the class blue.

Comment: No need of two `foreach()` check other answer and you will get a more easy solution

Comment: Yeah made sense after you made the edit to your answer.